# Intuitive way to understand the Smith–Volterra–Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, descriptive-set-theory, cantor-set

The Smith–Volterra–Cantor set (or ε-Cantor set) is a set of points on $ℝ$ that is nowhere dense, yet has positive measure.

As I understand it, being nowhere dense means containing no intervals. An interval is a set of real numbers where any number that lies between two numbers in the set is also included in the set.

How is it possible to have such a set on the real line where there are no intervals, yet the set still has positive measure? Can't we always simply pick two numbers from equal distance of any number in the set, thus creating an interval? Wouldn't removing all such options result in having no measure?

Comment: No, being a nowhere dense set means avoiding *a lot* of intervals. The rational numbers are a dense set, as are the irrational numbers. Compare their properties.

Comment: Formally, being nowhere dense means that, given any non-empty open interval, no matter how small, your set is not dense there. This implies, but is not equivalent to, the claim that the set contains no intervals.

Comment: Anyway, why would you think that having no intervals should imply that the set has no positive measure? Take any interval, and remove the rationals. If you agree that the rationals have measure zero, you need to agree that this set (which contains no intervals) has positive measure. Regardless, the *definition* of the measure of a set does not involve any computation related to the intervals contained in the set, so why do you think this is a requirement?

Answer (score 2):

"Can't we always simply pick two numbers from equal distance of any number in the set, thus creating an interval?"

Why does **that** define an interval? Sure maybe that defines the **endpoints** of some interval--but the point is that the Smith-Volterra-Cantor set *does not contain that interval*

One definition for "no-where dense" is *like you say*:
$A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a no-where dense set if and only if: 
For all intervals $J$ there exists a *subinterval* $I\subseteq J$ such that
$$
I \cap A = \emptyset 
$$
The point is that given any interval, we can find a subinterval inside of the given interval disjoint from $A$. Now, simply put, this means that given any interval $I$, $A\cap I$ is not dense in $I$. It does *not* mean that no-where denseness is equivalent to "containing no intervals".

Take for example $\mathbb{Q}$. $\mathbb{Q}$ contains no intervals but is dense in every interval. ($\mathbb{Q}\cap I$ for any interval $I$ will also not contain intervals, but of course is dense in $I$). The reasons why these examples fail our definition is because there is no **candidate subinterval** that we can find because *all* intervals intersect $\mathbb{Q}$.

*However*, a no-where dense set in $\mathbb{R}$ *does* have the property of not containing an interval.

Suppose there was an interval $K$ such that $A$ *did* contain $K$, as in, $K\subseteq A$. Well, by definition, there exists subinterval of $K$ that's disjoint from $A$--thereby showing that no such $K$ can exist. 
There's also an underlying topological notion here,  $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is no-where dense, if and only if cl($A$) is no-where dense. This is easy to see, as if cl($A$) is not nowhere dense, then there exists an $I$ interval such that for all $J$ subintervals of $I$, $J\cap I \ne \emptyset$. In particular, every point of of $I$ must be contained in cl($A$).  As, for example if $I=[a,b]$ then, consider $x\in I$, let $J_N=[x-\frac{b-a}{kN},x+\frac{b-a}{kN}]\subseteq [a,b]$. Where $k$ is sufficiently large. Every interval $J_N$ intersects cl($A$) in something, hence, we can extract a cauchy sequence in $A$ converging to $x$ from these subintervals, thus $x\in cl(A)$ because $cl(A)$ is closed and contains its limit points. This proof can be adapted for the endpoints. Thus, we get that $cl(A)$ contains $I$, which means that $A$ was dense in $I$ to begin with. For the other direction, if $cl(A)$ is no-where dense, then $A$ is no-where dense. Let $I$ be an interval, then there exists a $J$ such that $J$ is disjoint from $cl(A)$, then $J$ is disjoint from $A$ as $A\subseteq cl(A)$.

Your reasoning above is equating *having positive measure* with *containing intervals*. The whole point of the Smith-Volterra-Cantor set is that it's an *explicit* example that shows these two things **are not the same**.
"How is it possible to have such a set on the real line where there are no intervals, yet the set still has positive measure?"
Answer: Smith-Volterra-Cantor set.

Comment: " Now, simply put, this means precisely that "A contains no intervals". " Not quite, Russ. Being nowhere dense is more than simply containing no intervals, otherwise we would define it that way: Given any interval $I$, $I\setminus A\ne\emptyset$. But  $\mathbb Q$ contains no intervals and is dense. Being nowhere dense means that for any interval $I$, the set $A\cap I$ is not dense in $I$.

Comment: Russ, the definition you wrote is correct, the remark that followed is not. I am simply pointing out that the remark you make, "Now, ... intervals" is not accurate.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo You're right, my answer was short-sighted. I have edited my answer to reflect your comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove all rational numbers, certainly what is left contains no intervals. If you take $\varepsilon>0$ and list all rationals $\{q_n:n\in\Bbb N=1,2,..\}$ and remove an interval centered at $q_n$ of length $\varepsilon/2^n$, then the total length (or measure) removed will be at most $\varepsilon$, so what is left has large measure. On the other hand, what is left is nowhere dense, since its complement (consisting of all open intervals centered at rationals that were removed) is open and dense.

So if $C=[0,1]\setminus\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}\, (q_n -\frac\varepsilon{2^{n+1}},q_n +\frac\varepsilon{2^{n+1}})$, then $C$ is nowhere dense, but has measure $\ge 1-\varepsilon$. Specifically, for the Smith–Volterra–Cantor set one is careful in the construction to also ensure that $C$ is perfect (that is has no isolated points), but that is not difficult to achieve, in a similar way in which it is done for the usual Cantor set.